# Weasyprint showing - "Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file"

Tags: python, pdf, jinja2, msys2, weasyprint

To create a pdf using **weasyprint** installed **gkt** using **msys2** installer and given path in environment variable, but  **"Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file"** popping up.

```
# html to pdf creator libraries
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
from weasyprint import HTML
#from fpdf import FPDF

#other libraries
import base64
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile


def set_dll_search_path():
   if os.name != "nt" or not hasattr(os, "add_dll_directory"):
       return
   for p in os.environ.get("PATH", "").split(os.pathsep):
       try:
           os.add_dll_directory(p)
       except OSError:
           pass

set_dll_search_path()

................ code to get results ........................


....... loading results to pdf ..................

env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('.'))
template = env.get_template("myreport.html")

template_vars = {"title" : "Dashboard",
                 "table": df.sort_values(by = ['Bytes'],ascending=False).head(10).to_html(index= False),
                 'size_table' : size_summary.sort_values(by = ['Bytes'],ascending=False).to_html(index= False),
                 'time_table' : time_summary.sort_values(by = ['Bytes'],ascending=False).to_html(index= False),
                 'count_table' : result['count'],
                 'size' : result['size'],
                 'basename' : basename
                }

html_out = template.render(template_vars)

HTML(string=html_out, base_url='.').write_pdf("Table.pdf",stylesheets=["style.css"])
```

Comment: Can you provide the code where you import and use this library?

Comment: hello @SidKwakkel I have updated it in question.

Comment: Hello @SidKwakkel

Comment: I too encounter this problem when running a Python script in VS Code (it blocks report generation). Strangely however, when I run the same script in VS Code debug mode or via python command line, it works fine.